# Connecting JIRA restapi with java

Tags: java, rest, api, jira

I am coding using Jira RestApi with Java and I am unable to complete the task. Can anyone help me to solve this? I am unable to call the rest api here

```
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.*;

package jira.rest.api;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.COM.TypeLibUtil.IsName;

public class JiraManager {
    private final String m_BaseUrl = "http://localhost.:8080/rest/api/latest/";
    private String m_Username;
    private String m_Password;


    public JiraManager(String username, String password) {
        m_Username = username;
        m_Password = password;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void RunQuery() throws ClientProtocolException,
            IOException {

        String data = null;
        String argument = null;
        String method = "GET";
        String url = String.format("{0}{1}/", m_BaseUrl, "project");

        if (argument != null) {
            url = String.format("{0}{1}/", url, argument);
        }

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(m_BaseUrl);

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        String line = "";

        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {

            System.out.println(line);

        }

    }



    private String GetEncodedCredentials() {
        String mergedCredentials = String.format("{0}:{1}", m_Username,
                m_Password);
        byte[] byteCredentials = mergedCredentials.getBytes(Charset
                .forName("UTF-8"));
        String val = "";
        try {
            val = new String(byteCredentials, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return val;
    }

}
```

My main class calls the rest api using the following code:

```
package jira.rest.api;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;


public class main {


    public main() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClientProtocolException,
            IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String username = "sbodhuluri";
        String password = "Quad@2014";

        JiraManager manager = new JiraManager(username, password);
        manager.RunQuery();
        System.out.println("Hello and welcome to a Jira Example application!");

    }

}
```

Comment: What happens? Do you get an Exception? What's the result? Bloody hell..

Also, `GetEncodedCredentials` is never called.

Comment: your baseUrl has a dot after localhost, this might be the problem